# Change the color of the reference citation from bright green to black

Tags: bibliographies

I have this part in my thesis template and I want to change the citation color from bright green to black.

How can I change the citation color from bight green to black?

**text.tex**

```
\documentclass[
    11pt,
    english,
    twoside,
    a4paper,
    BCOR8.25mm,
    DIV10,
    headsepline,
    footsepline
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{a4}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[bookmarks=true,
                    bookmarksopen=true,
                    bookmarksnumbered=true,
                    colorlinks=true,
                    linkcolor=black                 
                    ]
                   {hyperref}

\begin{document}

Mowing down trees, flooding streets and battering buildings, Patricia hit land as a Category 5 hurricane on Friday evening before grinding inland. It moved quickly but lost power in the mountains that rise up along the Pacific coast and was downgraded to a tropical depression on Saturday morning as it headed through central Mexico \cite{recordingData}

        \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
        \bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

**bibliography.bib**

```
@article{recordingData,
  author = {Leon Stenneth and Ouri Wolfson and Philip S. Yu and Bo Xu},
  title = {Transportation Mode Detection using Mobile Phones and
GIS Information},
journal = {ACM DL},
  year = {2011},
    pages = {3}
}
```

Comment: What diabolical color is hell green?

Comment: `citecolor=green`?

Comment: @DG' About to edit that: It is german for bright green :-)

Comment: The options for `DIV` and `BCOR` are obsolete, as is package `a4`. But i think i have been telling you this already. Just to warn others that see the code.

Comment: Ok it works now after adding  `citecolor=black`. Thanks.